# How to connect Azure Web App with Databricks

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, databricks

Is it possible that a flask web app uploaded to the web app service can connect to databricks? The app should have some dropdown menus and send a command to databricks. Databricks should search the data from the data lake?.

Answer (score 2):

As I known, there are two ways to connect Azure Databricks in Python.

1. Refer to the offical document [`Connect to Azure Databricks from Excel, Python, or R`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/connect-databricks-excel-python-r), you can download and install `Simba Spark ODBC Driver` and `pyodbc` to follow the section [`Connect from Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/connect-databricks-excel-python-r#connect-from-python) to retrieve the data from Azure Databricks. However, I don't think you can follow the Simba offical document [`About the Simba Spark ODBC Driver for Windows`](https://www.simba.com/products/Spark/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/hi/intro.htm) to install and configure the driver on Azure WebApp for Windows, but you can try to follow the document [`About the Simba Spark ODBC Driver for Unix/Linux`](https://www.simba.com/products/Spark/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/unix/content/odbc/hi/intro.htm) to do on Azure WebApp for Linux.
2. Alternatively, there is a Python package named [`databricks-connect`](https://pypi.org/project/databricks-connect/), as its description said as the figure below, you can try to use it to connect custom applications like `flask` to Azure Databricks clusters and run Spark code.

   [image]

   The more details for its usage, you can refer to the offical document [`Databricks Connect`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/dev-tools/db-connect.html) and the blog [`Databricks-Connect - FINALLY!`](https://datathirst.net/blog/2019/3/7/databricks-connect-finally).

Hope it helps.